# Not able to get value from the result set

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

In my Servlet program I stored result set values in Session variable, when I am trying to access it in my JSP page, it is not displaying any value.

where I did wrong?

[image: code]

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you should edit your question to include the code as text in the actual question, rather than using a screenshot.

Comment: try please items="${sessionScope.f}" in jsp.

Comment: Are you sure your f is not empty? Debug it

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt when I use "${sessionScope.f}"  in my JSP its displaying [community.backend.entity.FileDetails@24587911, community.backend.entity.FileDetails@2c745dbb, community.backend.entity.FileDetails@bb5b6ca]

Comment: Here is my code     `code`
              
                List<FileDetails> f = new ArrayList<FileDetails>();
                rs = (ResultSet) selectstatement.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()) 
                {
                    FileDetails fd = new FileDetails();
                    fd.setId(rs.getString("id"));
                    fd.setCreatedon(rs.getTimestamp("createdon"));
                    f.add(fd);
                }
                 session.setAttribute("f", f); `code`

Comment: use ${sessionScope.f} with foreach, as you did in jsp.

Comment: Its working with <td><c:out value="${fnote.createdon}" /></td>  Thank You